# How to run ./gradlew build with docker gitlab runner?

Tags: docker, gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

So I am trying to make my pipeline work, but I keep getting stuck.

I have a docker runner for my git-ci.yml file
I do this because my deploy stage errors with shell runners (but my build, test and sonarqube stage do work with the shell runner)

```
**git-ci.yml**

image: docker:latest
      
stages:
   - build
   - sonarqube-check
   - test
  - deploy

cache:
  paths:
    - .gradle/wrapper
    - .gradle/caches

 build:
   stage: build
   image: gradle:jre11-slim
   script:
     - chmod +x gradlew
     - ./gradlew assemble
   artifacts:
     paths:
       - build/libs/*.jar
     expire_in: 1 week
   only:
     - master

 sonarqube-check:
   stage: test
   image: gradle:jre11-slim
   variables:
     SONAR_USER_HOME: "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.sonar"  # Defines the location of the analysis task cache
     GIT_DEPTH: "0"  # Tells git to fetch all the branches of the project, required by the analysis task
   cache:
     key: "${CI_JOB_NAME}"
     paths:
       - .sonar/cache
   script: ./gradlew sonarqube
   allow_failure: true
   only:
        - master

 test:
   stage: test
   script:
     - ./gradlew check



deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: gradle:latest
  script:
  - apt-get update -qy
  - apt-get install -y ruby-dev
  - gem install dpl
  - dpl --provider=heroku --app=heroku-coalition --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY
  - echo "This job deploys something from the $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH branch."
  only:
  - master
    


after_script:
  - echo "End CI"
```

First I got errors about my java home so I switched the image for the build stage. Now I did that and keep getting errors about the permission so I added the chmod +x gradlew

But I get this error when I add that line:

> chmod: changing permissions of 'gradlew': Operation not permitted

And when I remove the chmod gradlew line I get:

> /bin/bash: line 115: ./gradlew: Permission denied

So now I do not really know what to do.
In short: Which runner should I use to get this yml file to work, or how would I need to edit this yml file accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

So after some research I came across the `tags` keyword in gitlab. This enables you to run 2 runners for 1 yml file. In this way I could use a shell runner for my build, test and sonarqube fase and a docker runner for my deploy fase!

Comment: Would be nice to see an example of the above re: 2 different runners with the tags keybword. Also, would be nice to see the ```gradlew``` solution. Thanks in advance.